# Finding the probability density of wave function using numpy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find the probability density function of the schrodinger equation using an initial condition. The initial condition I have is this:

[image]

The constants are:

```
L      = 100
x0     = 15
v      = 16
sigma2 = 5
tmax   = 4
```

My code for the gaussian and finding the normalised initial condition so that the probability density function is equal to 1 over the interval 0 to L is:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
dx = 1/32
x = np.linspace(0, L, N)
func = lambda x: my_gaussian(x)*my_gaussian(x).conjugate()
C,e = quad(func, 0, L)
psi = (C**-(1/2))*my_gaussian(x)
```

However, in jupyter I get this message when I run the above code. It works but Im not sure if it is doing what it is supposed to:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:463: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
```

So does my above code correctly compute the normalised gaussian initial condition? If there is anything you would like me to add or explain please let me know. The code is supposed to make my wavefunction have the following condition: [image]

Comment: It looks right. I think `_quadpack._qagse` sees that `my_gaussian(x)*my_gaussian(x).conjugate()` is a complex number even though the imaginary part is zero. To get rid of the warning, and get some peace of mind, you can try replacing `my_gaussian(x)*my_gaussian(x).conjugate()` with ``abs(my_gaussian(x))**2``

Comment: @piterbarg thanks :)

Comment: sure. by the way you can pass `numpy.inf` instead of L to `quad` and it will figure out the right upper limit itself (assuming you want infinity as the upper limit and using L as a proxy for that)